# Uneven squares in grid image upon saving

Tags: python, matplotlib

So, I am trying to save a matplotlib figure as a TIFF. The image has all of the correct information and content but for some reason, after saving, the squares on the grid that I plot appear uneven. In the matplotlib image window that comes up after running the code though, the image has perfect squares. I have attached a code snippet and samples of the produced images below. They are screenshots of a much larger, 332x335 grid. The image generally looks okay but if it is to be used in scientific papers, as I intend, it should be as close to perfect as possible. If someone could help here, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
fname = tif_file_name+'.tif'
aspect = grid_x/grid_y
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(circ_avg, cmap='gray', aspect=aspect, interpolation='none',)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.savefig(fname, dpi = 1000, format='tif', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0)
plt.show()
```

Perfect squares from screenshot in plt.show() window:
[image: Perfect squares from screenshot in plt.show() window]

Uneven squares when viewed after saving:
[image: Uneven squares when viewed after saving]

Answer (score 1):

I was actually able to resolve this. It turns out the more effective way of doing this is by using the PIL library. This also greatly reduced the overall file size.

```
from PIL import Image

#scale to pixel vals (only multiplied by 255 here since my data already had 1 as the maximum)
vals= orig_vals*255
final_image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(vals), mode='L')
final_image.save('blah.tif')
```